# Visual Studio, how to add a project, but not save changes to the original project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I want to add a project to a solution and make changes to it, but I don't want those changes to be saved to the original project (the changes will NEVER be needed again). How do I do this?

Comment: by taking a copy of the original project?

Comment: I believe there is no built in way to do this rather than taking a backup copy of the original project.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you don't want the changes to the original *solution* to be saved.

I would simply take a backup of the solution file, and put it back again afterwards. If your solution is in source control, simply revert it.

You could *try* making the solution file read-only, but I suspect that Visual Studio will complain.

Comment: @Joey: "Did not work" is incredibly vague. What happened? Had you made changes to other projects as well as simply adding the new project? Please be more specific.

Comment: Change it then revert it sounds the best to me!